# rich:calendar ignored format pattern for the day of the week after selecting

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, simpledateformat

As a part of , I am using  component with settled value of datePattern as follows:

```
<rich:calendar id="effectiveDate" 
value="#{itemBean.effectiveDate}" 
datePattern="EEEE, MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

So when I load the form, the existing effectiveDate from the requested itemBean is properly displayed in the text field.

Problems:

1. when clicking on calendar icon, the content of the text field will be gone. So if I didn't select anything  from the calendar popup, then the text field remains empty.
2. when the date is selected it is displayed like that (for example):

EEEE, 11/19/2012
So the week day is not displayed properly.

Noticed that without specifying the week day (EEEE part of datePattern) none of mentioned above problems occurs.

Is there some specific way to display the week day after selecting?

I am on RichFaces 4.2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think this is a known issue with `<rich:calendar>`. I don't know much about that.
However try this,

```
<rich:calendar id="effectiveDate" value="#{itemBean.effectiveDate}" onchanged="formatCalendarString(event, this);" datePattern="EEEE, MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

Within `<head></head>` tags put this.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function formatCalendarString(event, cal) {
            var date = new Date(Date.parse(event.rich.component.getSelectedDate()));
            var weekdays=new Array(7);
            weekdays[0]='Sunday';
            weekdays[1]='Monday';
            weekdays[2]='Tuesday';
            weekdays[3]='Wednesday';
            weekdays[4]='Thursday';
            weekdays[5]='Friday';
            weekdays[6]='Saturday';

            var day = weekdays[date.getDay()];
            if(typeof(day) !== 'undefined') {
              var formattedDate = (day + ', ') + event.rich.component.getSelectedDateString().substring(6);
              cal.value = formattedDate;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I am using templates with several including, it would be a bit tricky (for me) to place the script properly, so the calendar would find it. Another thing -- relations between events of this particular calendar and value displayed in the form is not so straightforward. I already started thinking that switching to something else (like PrimeFaces's calendar) would be easiest way of doing in this situation.